# Azure Kubernetes - 'az acs create' and exceeding free account quota

Tags: azure-container-service

Trying to do an equivalent of my [MongoDB on GKE blog post](http://pauldone.blogspot.co.uk/2017/06/deploying-mongodb-on-kubernetes-gke25.html), for Azure Container Services instead, but failing at first hurdle. My blog posts are based on using the quotas available in each cloud provider's free tier/account, to help new users evaluate options before proceeding with paid tier. However having created an Azure free account, I can't seem to create a k8s cluster that stays under the "core limits" (I assume meaning keeping under the free threshold equivalent to "vCPUs", in this case).

When I run following:

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type kubernetes --resource-group MongoResourceGroup --name MongoK8sCluster --generate-ssh-keys
```

The result is:

```
Deployment failed. { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "An error has occurred in subscription 0657d162-d822-48f5-bbe9-4bcaac4f40e4, zesourceGroup: MongoResourceGroup request: Provisioning of resource(s) for container service MongoK8sCluster in resource group MongoResourceGroup failed. Message: {\n  \"code\": \"QuotaExceeded\",\n  \"message\": \"Provisioning of resource(s) for container service MongoK8sCluster in resource group MongoResourceGroup failed. Message: Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 8.. Details: \"\n }. Details: <no value>."
```

I tried to specify a smaller type of VM, but I don't seem to quite get there:

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type kubernetes --resource-group MongoResourceGroup --name MongoK8sCluster --agent-vm-size Standard_A0 --generate-ssh-keys

Deployment failed. { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "An error has occurred in subscription 0657d162-d822-48f5-bbe9-4bcaac4f40e4, resourceGroup: MongoResourceGroup request: Provisioning of resource(s) for container service MongoK8sCluster in resource group MongoResourceGroup failed. Message: {\n  \"code\": \"QuotaExceeded\",\n  \"message\": \"Provisioning of resource(s) for container service MongoK8sCluster in resource group MongoResourceGroup failed. Message: Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 5.. Details: \"\n }. Details: <no value>.
```

Any suggestions for getting the k8s sample project core count down enough to be within the free account thresholds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acs#create default agent-count is 3 and default master-vm-size is Standard D2_v2. This makes core requirement to be

```
3(agents)*1(core) + 1(master)*2(core) = 5
```

Since you have 4 core available, you should try setting :

```
 1. agent-count to be 3
 2. agent-vm-size to be Standard_A0
```

or

```
 1. agent-count to be 1
 2. agent-vm-size to be Standard_D11_v2
```

I would prefer option (2) because this will give sufficient memory and IOPS on the agent node. Keep the master-vm-size default as `Standard D2_v2` because etcd and kubenetes containers need sufficient memory for operation.

Comment: Great info. Option 2 worked worked for me using command line: az acs create --orchestrator-type kubernetes --resource-group MongoResourceGroup --name MongoK8sCluster --agent-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0):

Using the following configurations will be helpful.

- --master-count 1 => Standard_A2 (2 cpu)     => 2 cpu
- --agent-count 2 =>  Standard_A1 (1 cpu x 2) => 2 cpu

This configuration will create a cluster with in the free acount limits

```
az acs create -n "your-kubernetes-cluster" -g your-resource-group --master-vm-size Standard_A2 --agent-count 2 --agent-vm-size Standard_A1 --dns-prefix kube --orchestrator-type kubernetes --debug
```